# How to use "\" in latex

Tags: formatting

I am struggling with how to include the character `\` without it being a command. For a similar problem with `%` I would just use `\%`, but obviously `\\` is just a page break. Am I just being stupid?

Comment: Try `\textbackslash` and `\%`

Answer (score 0):

For those kind of problem [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)
is your friend.

`\textbackslash` în textmode